# How to remove duplicate lines - only in certain sections? Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, duplicates, extract

I am trying to consolidate a .txt file into a cleaned version of the data. Currently, the file is structured as the following:

```
IDENTIFIER: unique values

DATA ONE: more unique values

DATA TWO: more unique values

DATA TWO: more unique values

DATA TWO: more unique values

IDENTIFIER: unique values

DATA ONE: more unique values

DATA TWO: more unique values

DATA TWO: more unique values

IDENTIFIER:
```

And so on, for about ~500 'identifiers.' I want to read this file, and simply remove the duplicate "DATA TWO:"s. While I am familiar with how to simply remove duplicate lines, I need to remove the duplicates for each unique section, to yield:

```
IDENTIFIER: unique values

DATA ONE: more unique values

DATA TWO: more unique values
```

The amount of "DATA TWO:'s varies per identifier, usually two or three. It does not matter which of the "DATA TWO's" is printed to the new file; although each is worded slightly differently, they capture what I am trying to find, and any one would suffice.

I am relatively new to programming, using Python 2.7.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt") as f, open("out.txt", "w") as out::
    found = False
    for line in f:
        # new section always reset flag
        if line.startswith("IDENTIFIER:"):
            out.write(line)
            found = False
        # if first time we have seen DATA TWO write and set flag to true        
        elif line.startswith("DATA TWO:") and not found:
            out.write(line)
            found = True
        # ignore lines with "DATA TWO:" if we have already found one in the current section and continue
        elif line.startswith("DATA TWO:"):
            continue
        # else write the other lines in the section
        else:
            out.write(line)
```

Output using your example input:

```
IDENTIFIER: unique values
DATA ONE: more unique values
DATA TWO: more unique values
IDENTIFIER: unique values
DATA ONE: more unique values
DATA TWO: more unique values
IDENTIFIER:
```

Answer (score -2):

You can easily do this by using sets. For instance if you have a list [1,1,3,3,4,4], by doing set([1,1,3,3,4,4]) you obtain [1,3,4] which is a set.

```
>>> lines_lst = open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
>>> lst_set = set(lines_lst)
>>> output  = open('cleanfile.txt', 'w')
>>> for line in lst_set:
        output.write(line)
```

Bear in mind that this solution does not preserve order.